# variable must be equal to a numerical value C#

Tags: c#, .net

I cant figure out how to make this condition work, all i need is to check if the two variables are equal to a numeric value, then execute code as shown below. Is this the correct approach to take? if not, any suggestions?

```
decimal operand1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand1.Text);
decimal operand2 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperand2.Text);

if (operand1 & operand2 == any numerical value between 1 and 99999)
{
    // if true execute this
}
else
{
    //if false execute this
}
```

Comment: You mean if the two variables fall within a range? Two variables cannot equal another unless they are equal to each other.

Comment: When you say "numerical value", do you mean it'll be an integer? Or did you choose "Decimal" because it could have a decimal value to it?

Comment: You should check this variable  fall within this given range. as @Crowcoder said you can not check unless they are equal.

Comment: Welcome Konrad.   Is you goal to determine if both text expression follows the syntax of a decimal floating point number?

Comment: Is `any numerical value between 1 and 99999` just a placeholder for an actual variable that you expect to have? So if someone inputs `3` and `3`, will that always meet your criteria, or are you trying to ensure that both inputs are equal to a specific third number?

Comment: No one understands what you're trying to do. Please add a few examples and tell us if they are true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> all i need is to check if the two variables are equal to a numeric value,

The description of your problem and the description in the code are different.  In the code you say you need to check to see if two variables *are equal to any value in a particular range*, not *equal to a specific value*. Let's assume you mean the latter.

> Is this the correct approach to take?

No.  `&` has a particular meaning when applied to numbers, and it does not apply to decimals.

My advice for beginners is:  **when you are trying to represent a new concept, make a method that represents that concept**.  You can then refine that method as your skills improve.

When designing a method, think about: *what goes in, and what comes out*.  We want a decision to be made, so a `bool` comes out. What goes in? The value we wish to test, and the range:

```
static bool IsInRange(decimal value, decimal low, decimal high)
{
```

OK, what are the conditions by which this thing can be false?  If the value is lower than `low`, its not in the range, so say that:

```
  if (value < low)
    return false;
```

Similarly:

```
  if (value > high)
    return false;
```

We've now considered all the false cases, so the only remaining cases are always true:

```
  return true;
}
```

Now we have a tool that we can use.

```
if (IsInRange(operand1, 1m, 99999m) && IsInRange(operand2, 1m, 99999m)) ...
```

Are we done?  No.  **Always ask yourself if there is a way to make the program more clear.** There is:

```
const decimal low = 1m;
const decimal high = 99999m;
if (IsInRange(operand1, low, high) && IsInRange(operand2, low, high)) ...
```

Now if you decide to change the range, you only have to do it once.  And now the *meaning* of 1m and 99999m is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the condition separately and then combine them:

### Check if operand1 is between 1 and 99999:

- operand1 is greater than or equal to 1: `if(operand1 >= 1)`
- operand1 is less than or equal to 99999: `if(operand1 <= 99999)`

Combining them: `if(operand1 >= 1 && operand1 <= 99999))`

### Check if operand2 is between 1 and 99999:

- operand2 is greater than or equal to 1: `if(operand2 >= 1)`
- operand2 is less than or equal to 99999: `if(operand2 <= 99999)`

Combining them: `if(operand2 >= 1 && operand2 <= 99999)`

### Combining whole condition

```
if ((operand1 >= 1 && operand1 <= 99999) && (operand2 >= 1 && operand2 <= 99999))
{
            //stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the test into two conditions. Currently you are using the bitwise OR (which is used for binary arithmentic).
This is how your code should look (assuming you have a variable `'numerical'`, you want to test:

```
if (operand1 == numerical && operand2 == numerical)
{
   // if true execute this
}
```

Now both operands must be equal to numerical.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP had obviously made a mistake when trying to compare the values.

Comment: Yeah, the OP was a little vague, but I'm reading it the same way you are. A bitwise OR would be incorrect because inputs of `1` and `2` would have falsely returned true if `numerical` was `1`. Your answer seems the most correct to me, barring any clarification from the OP.

Comment: plus OP wants to check if value is 1-9999

Comment: I read the question as: compare both values with a third value of his choice.